# Difference between (unsigned cast)value and writing value?

Tags: c, types, casting

What is the difference between the two following line expressions:

```
#define value (unsigned char) 0x1f 
#define value 0x1fu
```

I usually find both expressions in examples in single .c file. Is there any difference between, concerning compiler behavior ?

Comment: I have never seen any of those and sincerely hope I never will. This will not compile. Please check _exactly_ what you meant to type and fix your question.

Comment: Guys, let's cut Georgiev some slack. The missing macro identifier is easily fixed.

Comment: I **forgot to type in the identifier**, really sorry!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we fix the broken macros to use an identifier, the difference between

```
#define FOO (unsigned char)0x1f
```

and

```
#define FOO 0x1fu
```

is their *type*. The type of the first definition is `unsigned char`, that of the second is `unsigned int`. You can see this when you compute the result of the `sizeof`operator on each:

```
printf ("%zu\n", sizeof(FOO));
```

which will likely output different values.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those work, the difference is not existant since neither of those work. Now if you mean:

```
#define var 0x1f
```

Means that literal use of the phrase `var` will from now on equal `0x1f`

```
#define var (unsigned char) 0x1f
```

Means that literal use of the phrase `var` will from now on equal `(unsigned char) 0x1f`

The difference beeing that the first var is `0x1f` in default assumed int form. Means an integer literal (equivalent to 31). The second is an integer literal cast to an unsigned char (still equivalent to 31 in int value, but now more like `'\31'`)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question about the difference between the 2 `#define..`.

Comment: @mch it is, as the first sentence clearly denotes that neither of those are valid statements. But I've edited in the actual difference at the bottom, for completeness's sake